# How can i downgrade bootstrap version with npm package.json

Tags: javascript, json, nuxt.js, devtools

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0"
  }
```

this is my current package.json so i would like to downgrade to an older version

Comment: Change the version `^5.1.0` to the version that you want to use. Then delete the bootstrap directory from the `node_modules`. Re-run `npm install` to install the changed version.

Comment: You can get the version number as in https://prnt.sc/1qv2b7u from this url https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

use `npm install [package-name]@[version-number]` to install a specific version of any package. in your case you can install any version of bootstrap using `npm install bootstrap@version`.

or as @BadPiggie mentioned in comments change the version of the bootstrap in package.json file then install packages using `npm install`.

you can see all versions of a package on the [npm website](https://www.npmjs.com).

Comment: Thank you it works but i got another problem